# Where's my possible duplicate auto comment?

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, automatic-comments

This morning I voted to close [C# serialize private class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314982/c-sharp-serialize-private-class-member) as a duplicate of [Serializing private member data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802711/serializing-private-member-data)

I can see that I definitely voted to close as a duplicate (this is the only close vote showing for this post):

[image: screen shot of the close dialog]

But there is no comment:

[image: screenshot of comments]

The sidebar for the question doesn't even show that question as a linked question despite the fact that my duplicate vote and the accepted answer both linked to that question.

What gives?

Comment: Hypothesis: the same URL was named in a comment by someone else, and that comment has since been deleted. The URL being present already prevents the auto-comment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought a deleted comment might have that impact (and/or expired close votes), but then why doesn't it show up as linked even though the accept answer links to the question

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's correct. There's a deleted comment from back in 2010 that linked to the same question.

Comment: @Adam 28 months later, any updates about fixing the bug?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have the fix committed locally, will push it live tomorrow.

Comment: @Adam awesome! Can you please take a quick look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283090/automatic-comment-was-not-added-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate) to see if it's the same issue, or something different? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of earlier today, we ignore deleted comments when checking to see if a "possible duplicate" comment already exists.

Comment: What is the reason for it?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson It's in the bug report.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson That's how the code works with this fix in place. Before the fix, if the "possible duplicate" comment was deleted, we wouldn't create another one even though we should.