# Why is my flag not displayed as a comment in the question?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

I flagged the question below two hours ago; see the image.

It shows that I flagged it as a duplicate.

[image: Screenshot of pending duplicate flag]

But in the question, the flag is not displayed in the comments.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200019/settextappearance-deprecated-android-how-to-use) is the link to the question.

What is this? Can anyone explain it to me or is this a bug?

Comment: Most likely a deleted comment... see [Where's my possible duplicate auto comment?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250193/wheres-my-possible-duplicate-auto-comment)

Comment: @psubsee2003 that's means if someone can flag same link before me and delete it then my flag comment can't see @ Martijn Pieters say..

Comment: The system is designed to prevent duplicating the comment, so if that link appears in an earlier comment, it won't be automatically created when you flag or vote to close.  It appears as if the system is also looking at deleted comments for the link as well, and the preliminary feedback at that time is it was a bug.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Is this `flag` is count or not in the Total flag..

Comment: Do you mean does it count as a helpful flag for you?

Comment: @psubsee2003 yes it is question ???

Comment: @ironman the comment is irrelevant to how your flag is processed. With or without comment, if enough reviewers agree with your flag, it'll be marked as helpful

Comment: Interestingly - for that post - the timeline shows that when you flagged as a duplicate, it auto posted the comment, you then deleted that comment 8 seconds later... The post is still currently sitting in the CV queue and depending what happens with that will be the result of your flag.

Comment: @Patrice Thnx for the Information..

Answer (score 8):

The reason you can't see the comment on the post is because you deleted it.

- 2016-07-05 09:42:21 - you flagged as duplicate and the comment: "possible duplicate of setTextAppearance deprecated in API level 23" was posted.
- 2016-07-05 09:42:29 - you deleted the comment.

If you look at the other duplicate flags you've raised - you'll notice your comment is still present on the posts.

The question is currently in the CV queue - so the outcome of your flag being marked helpful/declined will depend on the result of the CV review.

Comment: Thanks for Info. But I can't delete the comment. @ Martijin Pieters comment it can be put by someone and delete it.

Comment: The system posts the comment under your name so you're the author and the author of a comment may delete it. Somehow - you managed to do so in this case... Normally, you'd let the comment stay there so other people can see in the comments there's a suggested duplicate (so it can be up for discussion or fairly obvious) - if the question is then closed as a duplicate, the Community user will remove the comment on your behalf...